# add notifications to notification center panel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, notificationcenter

I have an iOS 5 pager application.
Application can receive new message counter from server.
For example application received 5 as a response from server.
So no I need to create new (or update existing) notification in notification center panel
and additionally I need the notification center to receive these notifications while the application is in background.
Help me please. How can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the developer documentation from Apple or the WWDC videos from 2011. There are thorough explanations and sample projects to get you started.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to google them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the information you require is in Apple's iOS Developer docs: [About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)

You also might want to look into the introductory video from WWDC2011: [Using local and push notifications on iOS and Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=517)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check the link that you provided

Comment: Haven't seen a single word about notification panel :(

Comment: The thing is, as it turns out you can't control the notification center. This is all in the hands of the user. But, by default any local notification you push to the user is added to the notification center when the user doesn't immediately react to it (tap okay in alert / slide icon on home screen). There's a lot of questions like this on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notificationcenter)

Comment: The notification centre is a method of organising sent notifications. There is no way of undoing sent notifications.